# How to make 3D text labels look like coplanar with specific axes planes?

Tags: python, matlab, plot, axis-labels

This is the same question for different implementations.
I am requesting Matlab or Python implementations for the label effects below:

[image]

PS: either by Matlab or Python is OK .

The mathematica version of this question is as in this link:
[question on Mathematica implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59129/how-to-obtain-sheared-text-label-effects)